# Factoring out common elements of Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, build-process, pom.xml

I have a number of Maven pom.xml files in various projects that contain a lot of similar configuration (license declarations, plugins, defintion of resource folders etc.)

What is the best approach to factor out these common elements into a parent pom and have them available for re-use?

I'm particularly interested in:

- What should go in the parent pom vs. being project specific?
- Where to store the parent pom, e.g. on GitHub?
- Any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: of the stuff you mention, i wouldn't use a common pom for licenses, plugins for different project. I would use the user settings http://maven.apache.org/settings.html for mirrors, servers, etc and a common pom for each different project as parent pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enterprise projects, you can use Maven to deploy your parent pom on a artifact repository like [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). But this can be cumbersome for just personal projects.

Everything that needs to be shared must be in parent pom.